# Why adding business controller class namespace in DNN makes module disappear?

Tags: search, module, controller, dotnetnuke

## I am trying to make a module searchable i DNN 9 so I created a class which implements ISearchable and overrides GetSearchItems.

following this documentation:
https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/isearchable

```
    public SearchItemInfoCollection GetSearchItems(ModuleInfo ModInfo)
    {
        SearchItemInfoCollection SearchItemCollection = new SearchItemInfoCollection();
        ArrayList Documents = GetDocuments(ModInfo.ModuleID, ModInfo.PortalID, true);

        foreach (var objDocument in Documents)
        {
            SearchItemInfo SearchItem;
            {
                var withBlock = (DocumentInfo)objDocument;
                int UserId = Null.NullInteger;
                // If IsNumeric(.CreatedByUser) Then
                // UserId = Integer.Parse(.CreatedByUser)
                // End If
                UserId = withBlock.CreatedByUserID;
                SearchItem = new SearchItemInfo(ModInfo.ModuleTitle + " - " + withBlock.Title, withBlock.Title, UserId, withBlock.CreatedDate, ModInfo.ModuleID, withBlock.ItemId.ToString(), withBlock.Title + " " + withBlock.Category, "ItemId=" + withBlock.ItemId.ToString());
                SearchItemCollection.Add(SearchItem);
            }
        }

        return SearchItemCollection;
    }
```

But when I add the namespace of the class in the module manifest, the module disappears from the page (and indexing doesn't work).

The namespace of the class is `ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController`

I have also tried `ProjectName.ListaNews` and changing it to `DotNetNuke.Modules.ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController`

I have tried changing the business class controller both from module settings and from .dnn file.

Why adding business class namespace breaks my module and makes it disappear from the page?

## -------------- EDIT ----------------

The business controller class name seems to be correct.
I checked the log file and found this error:

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection - ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController, ProjectName.ListaNews
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName.ListaNews' or one of its dependencies.

Cannot find specified file.
File name: 'ProjectName.ListaNews'
```

in `bin\` folder there is `ListaNews.dll`. I tried renaming it into `ProjectName.ListaNews.dll` but I had the same error (+ the site crash).

So I changed the business controller class to `ListaNews.ListaController, ListaNews` without `ProjectName` and it gave a new error:

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection - ListaNews.ListaController, ListaNews
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ListaNews.ListaController' from assembly 'ListaNews'.
```

Looks like it didn't find ListaController class.

I noticed ListaController.cs was not defined in .dnn file when I installed it.

I added this to the .dnn file

```
<component type="File">

    other files definitions....

    <files>
        <file>
        <name>ListaController.cs</name>
        </file>
    </files>
</component>
```

So I deleted and re-installed my module. Nothing changed though.

Does that give any hint?

Thanks

## -------------- EDIT 2 ----------------

Since it was a namespace error I moved the controller class from ListaController.cs to View.ascx.cs and the previous error disappeared, so the class is probably visible now. But the module is still not visible (crashes) so i checked the log and it gave 2 very similiar errors:

1)

```
Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

StackTrace: in System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) 
in System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
in DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.IsVesionableModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
in DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.InjectModule(ModuleInfo module)
in DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.InjectModule(Pane pane, ModuleInfo module)
```

2. 

```
InnerMessage: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

InnerStackTrace: at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModuleList(Int32 portalId)
```

I read System.Activator.CreateInstance documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Boolean_

and actually CreateInstance has a constructor with `type` parameter,
But I think it is called in DNN compiled libraries and I can't see what is going on

I added this line in constructor

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListaController));
```

and it logged this error:

```
Error Creating BusinessControllerClass
'ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController, ProjectName.ListaNews' of
module(ProjectName.ListaNews) id=(577) in tab(45) and portal(0)
StackTrace:
at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.ThrowLogError(ModuleInfo module,
Exception ex)

InnerMessage:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type
InnerStackTrace:
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at
system.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at
DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModuleList(Int32 portalId)
```

I found this forum
https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/495897/scope/posts/help-with-rror-in-custom-module
so I added a parameterless constructor in my controller class but it didn't change anything

Why is `type` null in CreateInstance?

Comment: This happens when the controller isn't defined properly (likely just naming). If you look at the LOGS in /portals/_default/logs you might get more details on the error.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I checked the log and edited the question with new information

Comment: You won't need to register the CS file in the .DNN file.

Comment: This is definitely a namespace issue, make sure that the namespace is correctly listed and the proper DLL.

Comment: @ChrisHammond It was a namespace error, I fixed it and now I get a different error. I edited the question with new details (in "EDIT 2" paragraph)

Comment: I feel like you're changing the topic too much and this is now a different question that deserves it's own thread

Answer (score 0):

The value for `businessControllerClass` in the manifest must be in the format `{FQCN}, {Assembly}`. This is per [The manifest schema](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/module-component)

For your project, assuming the namespace is as you mentioned `ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController` your assembly name is most likely `ProjectName.ListaNews` which would mean the proper value for the businessControllerClass is

```
ProjectName.ListaNews.ListaController, ProjectName.ListaNews
```

If that doesn't correct it, as Chris Hammond mentioned you can use the logs to get a more detailed error

Comment: Thanks Mitchel, I edited the question with new details. The business controller class format was the same as you suggested, but using a different namespace maybe changed something (always keeping the FQCN, Assembly format).